# How to put Gtk:Grid in Gtk:Window with gtkmm

Tags: gtkmm

How can I put Gtk:Grid in Gtk:Window using gtkmm. It says "*no known conversion for argument 1 from «Gtk::Grid()» to «Gtk::Widget&»*" when I'm trying to call `main_win.add(grid);`
This works but it's too ugly:

```
...
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

Main kit(argc, argv);

Label label1("Hello1",0,0.5);
Label label2("Hello2",0,0.5);

Grid grid;

(*((Container*)&grid)).add(label1);
(*((Container*)&grid)).add(label2);

Window main_win(Gtk::WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
main_win.add(*((Widget*)&grid));

main_win.show_all();

kit.run(main_win);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably more useful to show us what doesn't work.   Casting is rarely needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of those crazy casts.

```
Grid grid
Window window;
window.add(grid)
```

will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... Now it works... I think I did nothing... I'm not sure but it looks like `Grid grid();` was in my source code because it causes the same error.

Comment: This is an example of C++'s "most vexing parse", see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/240633